# Convert Feature Layer to an array of Polygons in ArcGIS JS?

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-js-api

Pretty straight forward: I am simply trying to get a feature layer

```
var floodLayer = new FeatureLayer("URL");
```

and convert it to a polygon array similar to:

```
var polygons = [];

for (var i = 0; i < floodLayer.graphics.length; i++) {
var polygons[i] = new Polygon({ "rings": floodLayer.graphics[i].rings, "spatialReference": floodLayer.graphics[i].spatialReference });
}
```

However, feature layers don't appear to have the appropriate properties to create polygons. Unless I am missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rings` and `spatialReference` are properties of `geometry` which is a property of your graphics. So you need to use `floodLayer.graphics[i].geometry.rings` instead of `floodLayer.graphics[i].rings`, for example.

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks Gavin!